# Xcode 6 shows iPhone 5 resolution when updating for iPhone 6/6+?

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus

I'm updating my apps for the iPhone 6/6 Plus resolutions by adding the launch storyboard. Most of them have updated perfectly fine since I'm using Auto Layout, but two of them don't seem to work properly. In the iPhone 6/6+ simulators they run with the iPhone resolution but in the top left hand corner of the screen, as [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leVqE.png) shows.

Any ideas to the cause?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like you are missing the constraints that resize the green area to all borders.

Comment: Is there a simple way to do that without reseting auto layout constraints?

Comment: The triangle button should have a "Add Missing Constraints"-option after you click on that green area.

Comment: Thanks for the response but it did a similar thing to Reset All Constraints and send everything all over the place unfortunately.

Comment: That really should not happen I think... at least Xcode can undo that, so it's not that dramatic. I'll see if something else comes to my mind.